# Receiving an "Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential" error after moving code to new machine

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I had .NET code that successfully requested a shared Google Sheet for about 3 years. I had a hard drive crash on my machine and I'm running the same exact code in the same folder from a backup and I'm now getting the below error on the new machine.

I've tried a few times to authorize the Service Account with Google OAuth 2.0 through the  gcloud CLI and it has popped up the browser and logged into the correct account that is linked to the application name.

I've changed the path for the Json credential to the one that the CLI reported it generated and get a scope error. The original Json credentials continue to work on another machine.

I've tried to get this working for about 4 hours now and can't help but think it's something simple.

```
            Dim _scopes As String() = {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets}
            Dim _applicationName As String = "xxx"
            Dim _spreadsheetId As String = "xxx"
            Dim _sheetsService As SheetsService
            Dim credential As GoogleCredential
            Dim range As String = "Data!A1:CT"


            credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(DecryptData(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\1.json")))


            Dim bIntializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
            bIntializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
            bIntializer.ApplicationName = _applicationName

            _sheetsService = New SheetsService(bIntializer)

            Dim Request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(_spreadsheetId, range)

            Dim Response As ValueRange = Request.Execute()







Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]

Errors [

    Message[Invalid Credentials] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[authError] Domain[global]

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Computer time was off by 10 minutes causing the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).